# Populate wp-login field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, authentication, form-fields

So on the wordpress login page of my site I want to have two buttons below the login box, each button containing login info for specific user. Admin and demo. How can I accomplish this with JavaScript and where would I throw the buttons, wp-login.php? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to implement some sort of hook on wordpress

More details on: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_form

Using this hook you can add another buttons as html or javascript code

```
add_action('login_form','login_extra_buttons');

function login_extra_buttons() {

    ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#user_login').value = 'demo';$('#user_pass').value = 'demo';">Demo Login</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#user_login').value = 'admin'; $('#user_pass').value = 'demo';">Admin Login</a>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man.  Would you suggest to put this in wp-login.php? Or as a part of a standalone plugin?

Comment: not in `wp-login.php` as it will get vanished when you upgrade you wordpress install, standalone plugin? you're on the right track

Comment: So I threw it up on my site to test it out in a plugin, The buttons show but when i click on them I get a 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a way to retrieve the info from the Wordpress database, this can't be done with JavaScript alone (or any client-side library for that matter). You have to modify wp-login and use the [Wordpress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs) to get the user info from your wordpress database first and then you can use Javascript to place it anywhere on the page.